# how to design business, branch and there services tables in database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have to create a database for a refrigerators service company. They service refrigerators in businesses and individuals. These businesses can have multiple branches as well. I'm in stuck with creating the database design for the business, branch, individual, service entities.

I initially thought of mapping the database as businesses has branches, and branches have services. But the problems were rise when some businesses have branches but some are not. so how to handle the services of businesses without branches or individuals.

```py
business table

| business_id | business_name |
|-------------|---------------|
| 1           | A company     |
| 2           | B company     |

branches table

| branch_id | business_id | branch_address |
|-----------|-------------|----------------|
| 1         | 1           | Address A      |
| 2         | 1           | Address B      |
```

I'm struggling with creating the services table which can have multiple services from businesses with branches or businesses without branches.

Comment: 'businesses and individuals' aren't these just customers

Comment: they are customers. but some customers have branches some are not. how to map customers with branches and customers without branches with their services. customers with branches have their service in their branch. others are having service directly.

Comment: you can create a customer , customer_branches and branch_service tables. When adding a customer add them to customer_branch as well with a tag (branch or not branch)

Comment: What are the use cases that require knowledge different types of customers?

Comment: actually there are no different types. I want to map the customers data with there services data. case here is some customers have branches, while others not. I need to map both types of customers to their services

Comment: You have to define (for us and yourself) what a branch and a service is in relation to it's main company. Usually, if you make a contract with a branch, you have a contract with that branch. Apple head quarter doesn't care where the apple store in new york gets it's refrigerator service from. Each branch is just a normal customer. If your business model is different (a contract always includes all branches), I'd probably treat them as locations, and you probably need a way to store individual locations/refridgerators anyway even for individuals (kitchen: AX29, 27years; garage: PPP11, 1 year).

Comment: Focus on each Branch being an entity.  And have a column that says what Business the Branch belongs to.